# Load tmx map at background with progress bar or loading scene

Tags: android, progress-bar, andengine, splash-screen, tmx

I use AndEngine and i have a large tmx map in 3000 * 3000 px. When i click to play button at menu scene for load game scene takes over 20 seconds to loading and wait at menu scene.i want to show progress bar or loading scene when tmx map is loading.
It's my code for loading tmx map in game scene.

```
try{

        TMXLoader tmxLoader=new TMXLoader(activity.getAssets(), activity.getTextureManager(),
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, vbom);
        this.mTMXTiledMap=tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("gfx/level1.tmx");
    }catch (final TMXLoadException e){
        Debug.e(e);
    }
```

Comment: I can't help you add a progress bar, but 20 seconds sounds way too long even for such a big map. Are you already using the base64+zlib option for storing the layer data? This should be quite fast.

Comment: yes i use the base64+zlib.it takse 3 second in bluestacks but in phone is long